# Angular 2 square brackets syntax error for ASP.NET MVC Razor Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I try to write some Angular 2 components and I am using ASP.NET MVC CSHTML Razor views as templates. And when I use quare brackets I got the following syntax error.

I am using VS 2015 Update 2.

I can compile it an everything is working fine. But its not cool that you think that there is something wrong with the written html. Is there something I can do to prevent the "Unexprected token" Error?

[image: Unexpected Token]

Comment: use an IDE with ng2 support? see vscode or webstorm

Comment: sry I need to use VS 2015 Update 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install Resharper 2016.1.2 then the problems are fixed with the newest Resharper Version.